# Aptitude question: interpretation of "some"

Tags: logic

I came across the aptitude test question that should test my logic reasoning skills. The task is to select those statements that follow from the given statements. The following statements are assumed to be true:

- (S1) All A are P.
- (S2) No B are A.

The solution states that from these two statements, we can conclude that

- (C1) No A are B.
- (C2) At least some P are A.

While I agree with (C1) because of the symmetry of the inequality relation, I don't understand why (C2) should follow from above statements. If there are no A, then statement (S1) still holds, while there are none P that are A, so (C2) doesn't hold.

What did I missed?

Comment: I agree with you that deducing $C_2$ would require the assumption that $A$ is non empty.  The statement "every person who can fly is a mathematician" does not imply that some mathematicians can fly.

Comment: Let $M$ be the set of objects that are "$A$" and $N$ the set of objects that are $P$. Then S1 means that $M$ is a subset of $N$ , and if $M$ is not empty , then every element of $M$ (just pick up one of it) satisfies C2 since it is also in $N$.

Comment: Of course there must be an element being "$A$" such that this works. Otherwise we have the vacous truth and cannot conclude anything about the objects that are "$P$".

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the hint, I fixed it.

Comment: So, you're basically agreeing with me. The question didn't mentioned anything about the magnitude of A, so I think (C2) cannot be concluded from the assertions.

Comment: It actually depends on what system you are working with. For syllogistic logic, "All S are P" implies "Some S are P." For first order logic (which is what modern mathematicians usually work with), you are indeed correct.

Comment: Yes you're correct about this the solution is wrong. "At least some P are A" does not follow.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Maybe, they were indeed not using the logic modern mathematicians use...